# How to move from dual boot to full installation?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I've been running Ubuntu in parallel to Windows on my SSD for the past year, through a dual boot. I'm really happy with Ubuntu and do not use Windows anymore.
I'd like to get rid of Windows but I'm not willing to re-install Ubuntu because I don't want to reconfigure all my customisation.
How should I do? Would it be enough to delete the Windows' partition and extend the Linux's partition?

Comment: Yes, it should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the Windows Partition. Extend the Linux partition provided that will not damage what's there already, and there's a risk with a mix of a Linux partition and an NTFS partition.  If in doubt, you could reformat the Windows partition and them mount it independently, perhaps as `/opt` or `/mystuff`, or replacing an existing partition like `/usr` or `/home`, but you'd need to copy everything across to do that, which itself carries risks.

Afterwards, you should also run:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo grub-install
```

which should remove the Windows entries from the grub menu.

Comment: I'd wanted to format like that, but couldn't see how. Now I can edit, I can see how it's done.  Thanks for reformatting for me.  Much better.